# Insert into database user inputs but not all of them show up

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I created a database(xampp) and userform(html+css+php+js)
i did i all icould find online but none help.
db:-formfills   table:-daata   form+dbinput:-index.php, insert.php

At this point i dont even know where i'm wrong. please help me!

## **HTML FORM (INDEX.PHP)**

```
<form name="UserProfile" action="insert.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

<label for="pic">FirstName</label>
<input type="file" id="pic" name="ProfilePicture" accept="image/*" required="">

<label for="FirstName">FirstName</label>
<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" required="">

<label for="LastName">LastName</label>
<input type="text" id="Last Name" name="Last Name" required="">

<label for="dob">DateofBirth</label>
<input type="date" id="dob" name="Date of Birth" value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>' required="">        

<label for="gender" >Gender</label>
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required=""> Male <br>
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required=""> Female <br>
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required=""> Other <br>

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="Email" required="">

<label for="country">Country</label>
<select id="country" name="Country">
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Others">Others</option>  
</select>        

<label for="number">Contact Number</label>
<input type="text" align=center id="code" name="Country Code"  value="+91">
<input type="number" id="num" name="ContactNumber" required="">

<label for="address">Address</label>
<textarea id="address" name="Address" required="" style="height:100px"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

## **INSERT.PHP**

```
<body>
    <center>
        <?php
        // servername => localhost
        // username => root
        // password => 
        // database name => formfills
        session_start();
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "formfills");       
        // Check connection
        if($conn === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. "
                . mysqli_connect_error());
        }       
        // Taking all 10 values from the form data(input)
        
                $pic = $_FILES["ProfilePicture"];
        $fname = $_REQUEST["FirstName"];
        $lname = $_REQUEST["LastName"];
        $dob = strtotime($_REQUEST['DateofBirth']);
        $dob = date('d-m-Y', $dob);
                $gender = $_REQUEST["Gender"];
        $email = $_REQUEST["Email"];
                $code = $_REQUEST["CountryCode"];
        $country = $_REQUEST["Country"];
                $num = $_REQUEST['ContactNumber'];
                $address = $_REQUEST['Address'];
        
                // Performing insert query execution
        // here our table name is daata
                $sql = "INSERT INTO daata VALUES ('$pic','$fname','$lname','$dob','$gender','$email','$code','$country','$num','$address')";
        
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            echo "<h3>data stored in a database successfully."
                . " Please browse your localhost php my admin"
                . " to view the updated data</h3>";

echo nl2br("$pic\n $fname\n $lname\n $dob\n $gender\n $country\n $code\n $num\n $address\n $email");
        } 
                else{
            echo "ERROR: Hush! Sorry $sql. "
                . mysqli_error($conn);
        }       
        // Close connection
            mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </center>
</body>
```

UPDATE
[Thanks @Professor Abronsius and @deceze for insights but I'll still need more help.
PS I also dont understand the publishing part(I copied that code from somewhere here)]

I can connect to db and insert all columns but not picture and gender. pls tell where i'm going wrong

Comment: ID attributes should not have spaces in them and probably better to treat name attributes the same - no spaces. Your `radio` input elements need values.

Comment: At least narrow it down a bit. What works and what doesn’t?

Comment: Your `image` will show up in the `$_FILES` array rather than `$_REQUEST`

Comment: Your SQL is wide open to sql injection and you need to further process the `$_FILES` array to correctly upload, save and log the image

Comment: `echo "ERROR: Hush! Sorry $sql. "` - why would you actually want to publish your SQL if there is an error? For debug purposes ok otherwise risky

Answer (score -2):

First thing try to check the connection
Check if the connection to the database is successful by adding an "if" condition after creating the connection. `if (!$conn) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }`

and also check this part of code
 `// Performing insert query execution // here our table name is daata $sql = "INSERT INTO daata VALUES`

Comment: OP already has ```if($conn === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. "
                . mysqli_connect_error());
        }``` there. There are lots of things to check in the code. If you write an answer, please provide some insight into _what_ should be fixed.

Comment: It's also my fault partially as i'm new to this stuff and not knowing what went wrong I just copied the whole thing omitting only the css part. Pls forgive me, once I learn more I'll update it ASAP.